# Is there any different between a Column-oriented DBMS and RDBMS when designing a database schema?

Tags: database, rdbms, column-oriented

Is there any different between these two kind of database? If yes, what is the different? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't really answerable because "RDBMS" and "column-oriented" refer to very different aspects of a DBMS and are not mutually exclusive.

A RDBMS is any DBMS that implements the relational model.

A column-oriented DBMS is any DBMS that uses a columnar storage for data. That could be an RDBMS or it could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

A column-oriented database is typically used for data warehouses and where you need to aggregate large amounts of data. It can be substantially different than a 'typical' transactional database.

Is this this what you are desiring to build (a data warehouse)?

Answer (score 0):

When the column-oriented DBMS supports SQL, it replaces the SQL schema internally with a fully normalised version. Therefore performance considerations in the design of the schema that usually apply to traditional RDBMS no longer apply.